# How can I create such a matrix?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, matrix

I'm new to javascript arrays. How can I create such a matrix?

```
[0, 1]
[3, 2]
[4, 5]
[6, 7]
[8, 9]
```

Comment: Yes.  A matrix can be an array of those arrays.

Comment: Add `[]` and commas and you're done, e.g. `[[0,1], [3,2], /* more elements */ ]`!

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is an array of arrays so just put those arrays into another array, assign it to a variable and you're ready to start using it in any way you want:

```
let matrix = [
   [0, 1],
   [3, 2],
   [4, 5],
   [6, 7],
   [8, 9]
];
```